# Inconsistent touch events

Tags: dojo

I am using Dojo's `touch.press()` and `touch.over()` combination for some drag action.

While debugging desktop Firefox, `touch.press()` event is a `mousedown` and `touch.over()` is a `mouseover`, everything works fine and the properties I need are available (`pageX`, etc).

Then I remote debug a mobile Chrome and what I get is:

**touch.press (GOOD):**

- a `TouchEvent` which contains `type="touchstart"`, `pageX` properties, and the `touches` array with one position (one finger) which itself has the expected properties (pageX, ...).

**touch.over (BAD):**

- a `Event` which contains `type="dojotouchover"`, but has no `pageX` or the `touches` array.

So the question is, is this a bug, should I do something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're listening to `touch.over` events rather than `touch.move` events ? As far as I understand, the synthetic event that a `touch.over` handler receives on touch devices does not includes all the informations from the original `touchmove` events that triggered it.

If you want to retrieve all the informations from the original event, I think you might actually listen to `touch.move` events.

Comment: Actually yes, it was touch.over. Maybe switching to touch.move fits my requirements better. Because somehow I was confusing over with move.